# How fast does a sum of Bernoulli distributions (of different parameters) decrease after its mean?

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, probability-distributions, bernoulli-trial

Let $X=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$, where each $X_i$ is a random variable following a Bernoulli distribution of parameter $p_i$. All $X_i$ are independent, and for all $i$,  $p_i<p$ for some small $p$. I'm trying to find an upper bound on:

$$
\frac{Pr[X=k]}{Pr[X<k]}
$$

assuming $k=\frac{Cpn}{1-p}$ for some constant $C>1$. When all $p_i$ are the same, I can directly use $Pr[X<k]>Pr[X=k-1]$; compute the ratio directly, and easily bound it by $1/C$. I suspect that this stays true if the $p_i$ are different, but smaller, but I can't manage to prove this. Any ideas?